# Rubymine Unused Method Highlighting

Tags: ruby, rubymine, sorbet

Is it possible for Rubymine to highlight unused methods if you aren't using a typing system like ruby 3 or sorbet has?

Comment: If your app isn't doing a lot of metaprogramming, just grep for method definitions and then count the number of matches excluding comments and redefinitions. Anything with more than one match is used somewhere; the rest are not.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there's no such possibility, please add you vote to the corresponding feature request on the RubyMine's tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-5878/Add-Method-is-never-used-inspection